# SQL Server Query_ToDelete_Records

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone help me with the script which will select the latest date from the column `dtUpdated_On` if date is greater than last date and ID is less than last ID. I know the question is not clear but try to understand. In this example I want to delete ID 1003 (I know in this example we will say... `Delete from tableName where ID=1003`)

```
ID         dtUpdated_On
-----------------------------------
1001       2009-12-11 20:08:16.857
1002       2012-03-31 02:35:16.650
1003       2012-09-01 00:00:00.000
1004       2012-03-31 02:35:16.650
```

Comment: So, you want to delete all the records where `dtUpdated_On` is greater then records with a greater Id? What version of sql server are you working with? Also, Please edit your question to include the relevant table DDL some sample data as DML and desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that by "last" you mean the row with the highest id, then you can do:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select top 1 dtUpdated_On
      from t
      order by id desc
     ) last
     on t.dtUpdated_On > last.dtUpdated_On;
```

You can also express this in the `where` clause, which is simpler for deletion (in my opinion):

```
delete t
where t.dtUpdated_On > (select top 1 t2.dtUpdated_On
                        from t
                        order by id desc
                       )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE(ID INT, dtUpdated_On DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @MyTable
VALUES   (1001, '2009-12-11 20:08:16.857')
        ,(1002, '2012-03-31 02:35:16.650')
        ,(1003, '2012-09-01 00:00:00.000')
        ,(1004, '2012-03-31 02:35:16.650')

;WITH LatestDate AS
(
    SELECT TOP 1 ID, dtUpdated_On
    FROM @MyTable
    ORDER BY dtUpdated_On DESC, ID DESC
),
LastestID AS 
(
    SELECT c.ID, c.dtUpdated_On, t.ID AS LatestID, t.dtUpdated_On AS LatestIDDate
    FROM @MyTable t
    INNER JOIN LatestDate c ON t.dtUpdated_On < c.dtUpdated_On
        AND t.ID > c.ID 
)

DELETE t
FROM @MyTable t
INNER JOIN LastestID c ON c.ID = t.ID

SELECT *
FROM @MyTable t
```